# Eigenvalues of a block matrix from the eigenvalues of the blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, block-matrices

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of the following complex matrix 
\begin{align}
M=\left(\begin{matrix}
A & B \\
B^\dagger & A^\dagger
\end{matrix}\right)
\end{align}
where the symbol $\dagger$ stands for the conjugate transpose of the matrix.

Is there an expression of the eigenvalues of $M$ as a function of $A$ and $B$, or their properties?

Or an upper bound?

Feel free to make some assumptions on $A$ and $B$, [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10958-005-0312-y) for instance, requires positive definiteness of the diagonal blocks. I haven't been able to find further research yet.

Comment: [cross-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327658/eigenvalues-of-a-block-matrix-from-the-eigenvalues-of-the-blocks?noredirect=1#comment818115_327658)

Answer (score 0):

If $A=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&x\\0&0}$, for a real number $x$, then all the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are zero, but the eigenvalues of $M$ are $x,-x,0,0$.

So the eigenvalues of $M$ are not determined by, or bounded by, the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: No, that is the wrong conclusion. You just showed that, in your example, the absolute value of the eigenvalues of $M$ is greater or equal than the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Moreover, [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10958-005-0312-y) does indeed show some bounds, albeit with positive definiteness assumptions.

Comment: @Astor No, I showed (by taking varying values of $x$) that the eigenvalues of $M$ are not determined by, or bounded by, the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. Given $A$ and $B$ with all eigenvalues zero, there is no bound on the eigenvalues of $M$.

Comment: @Astor But you didn’t mention positive definiteness.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I'll take that I may have to refine the question. Please feel free to make assumptions and we could achieve an answer (and a question) worth keeping.